# Equivalence of different ways of geometrical multiplication

Tags: euclidean-geometry, arithmetic, conic-sections, big-list, geometric-construction

There are at least five ways to multiply two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ given as integer points $A$ and $B$ on the number line by geometrical means. Two of them include counting, the others are purely geometric. I wonder (i) if there are other ways and (ii) how to deeply understand the interrelationship between the different methods (i.e. recipes).

Let $A,B$ be two integer points on the line $O1$:

[image]

### Method 1

1. Count how often the unit length $|O1|$ fits into $|OA|$. Let this number be $a$ (here $a = 3$).

[image]

2. Draw a circle with radius $|OB|$ around $B$.
3. Let $C$ be the (other) intersection point of this circle with the line $O1$.

[image]

3. Draw a circle with radius $|OB|$ around $C$.
4. Do this $a-1$ times.
5. The last intersection point $C$ is the product $A \times B$.

[image]

### Method 2

1. Construct a rectangle with side lengths $|OA|$, $|OB|$.

[image]

2. Count how often the unit square (with side length $|O1|$) fits into the rectangle. Let this number be $c$ (here $c=6$).

[image]

3. Draw a circle with radius $|O1|$ around $0$.
4. Let $C$ be the intersection point of this circle with the line $O1$.

[image]

4. Draw a circle with radius $|O1|$ around $C$.
5. Do this $c$ times.
6. The last intersection point $C$ is the product $A \times B$.

[image]

### Method 3

1. Construct the line perpendicular to $O1$ through $O$.
2. Construct the points $1'$ and $B'$.

[image]

3. Draw the line $1'A$.
4. Construct the parallel to $1'A$ through $B'$.
5. The intersection point of this parallel with the line $O1$ is the product $A \times B$.

[image]

### Method 4

1. Construct the perpendicular line to $O1$ through $O$.
2. Construct the point $1'$.
3. Construct the circle through $1'$, $A$ and $B$.
4. The intersection point of this circle with the line $O1'$ is the product $A \times B$.

[image]

### Method 5

This method makes use of the parabola, i.e. goes beyond compass-ruler constructions.

1. Construct the unit parabola $(x,y)$ with $y = x^2$.
2. Construct $B'$.
3. Construct the line perpendicular to $O1$ through $A$.
4. Construct the line perpendicular to $O1$ through $B'$.
5. Draw the line through the intersection points of these two lines with the parabola.
6. The intersection point of this line with the line $O1'$ is the product $A \times B$.

[image]

---

For me it's something like a miracle that these five methods – seemingly very different (as recipes) and not obviously equivalent – yield the very same result (i.e. point) $A \times B$.

---

Note that the different methods take different amounts $\sigma$ of Euclidean space (to completely show all intermediate points and (semi-)circles involved, assuming that $a >b$):

- Method 1: $\sigma \sim ab^2$
- Method 2: $\sigma \sim  ab$
- Method 3: $\sigma \sim  ab^2$
- Method 4: $\sigma \sim  a^2b^2$
- Method 5: $\sigma \sim  a^3b$

This is [space complexity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Space_complexity). Compare this to [time complexity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Time_complexity), i.e. the number $\tau$ of essential construction steps that are needed:

- Method 1: $\tau \sim a$
- Method 2: $\tau \sim  ab$
- Method 3: $\tau \sim  1$
- Method 4: $\tau \sim 1$
- Method 5: $\tau \sim  1$

From this point of view method 3 would be the most efficient.

---

Once again:

> I'm looking for other geometrical methods to multiply two numbers
>   given as points on the number line $O1$ (is there one using the
>   hyperbola?) and trying to understand better the "deeper" reasons why
>   they all yield the same result (i.e. point).

---

Those answers I managed to visualize I will add here:

### Method 6 (due to [Cia Pan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3155738/1792))

[image]

### Method 7 (due to [celtschk](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3155770/1792))

[image]

### Method 8 (due to [Accumulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3156059/1792))

[image]

Comment: IMVHO methods 1 and 2 do not count: when you use the word 'count', the method becomes arithmetical instead of geometrical.

Comment: @CiaPan:  a) I didn't claim that methods 1 and 2 are *purely* geometrical. But they are at least partially. b) What else is done in methods 1 and 2 in the "count" steps?

Comment: @CiaPan: This is why I believe that methods 1 and 2 are more geometrical than arithmetical: It's really only *counting* that is needed, but no "true" arithmetic, i.e. addition or multiplication. You may ask: But how does one really _count_ the number of unit squares (by which geometrical means), doesn't one essentially count $a$ and $b$ and then multiply them? If this must be so, you have won.

Comment: @CiaPan So methods that count don't count?

Comment: When you say _'count it – let $n$ be the numer – do something $n$ times'_ you introduce some counter $n$ and some variable 'iteration number' running from 1 through $n$. In my feeling this goes beyond classic constructions and I would translate it into purely geometric actions. For example in Method 1: construct a chain of consecutive copies of the segment $O1$ along the line, until you reach $A$; at each constructed endpoint construct a copy of $OB$ perpendicular to the line; construct a chain of consecutive copies of... (to be continued)

Comment: (cont.) ...all those segments along the line; the final endpoint is the point sought. This way we iterate over some set of concrete objects (segments or their endpoints). We can say 'I proces _this_ one, and now _this_ one... And I processed all of them so here is the result.' as opposite to 'I do one construction, and the second one... And I _remember_ I was to make five of them, so now I'm done.' which involves some criterion not visible in the drawing.

Comment: According to the [Mohr–Mascheroni theorem (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem), any point classicaly constructible by a straightedge and a compass can also be constructed by a compass alone. Applying this would turn all points in your recent list to "circle". :)

Comment: @CiaPan: I'll drop it.

Comment: There's another geometrical way to multiply that is not a compass+straightedge construction in the sense you're after since it requires 3 dimensions, but I find it quite beautiful so I can't resist to mention it. I described it in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210189/geometric-notion-of-addition-for-the-real-projective-line) (the first image). It requires constructing two lines of slope $a$ and $b$ first, its output is a line of slope $a \cdot b$.

Comment: This question should be retitled "Different ways of geometrical multiplication", or even "Equivalence of different ways of geometrical multiplication". Since that's what it's looking for. It's not just looking for a jumbled list without any discussion of equivalence (or "interrrelationship"). My edit on that was rejected; one of you can fix it if you care.

Comment: @smci: I: agree and changed the title.

Answer (score 6):

1. Construct the point $A'$ on the given line such that $O$ is a midpoint of the line segment $AA'$.
2. Construct the perpendicular at $O$.
3. Construct the semicircle on the diameter $A'B$.
4. Find $H$ at the intersection of the semicircle and the perpendicular.
   $(OH)^2 = OA'\cdot OB = OA\cdot OB$.
5. Draw line $1H$ and construct a perpendicular to it through $H$.
6. Find point $K$ at the intersection of the last constructed line and the first given line. We have $(OH)^2 = 1\cdot OK,$ hence $OK = OA\cdot OB.$

Answer (score 4):

The following is quite similar to your method 3, but only requires you to draw parallels, not circles (see remark below).

1. Draw an arbitrary line $g$ other than the number line through $O$. (The “number line” here is the line through $O$ and $1$).
2. Select on $g$ an *arbitrary* point $P$ other than the origin.
3. Draw a line through $1$ and $P$.
4. Draw a parallel to that line through $A$. Call the intersection with $g$ $Q$.
5. Draw a line through $P$ and $B$.
6. Draw a parallel to that line through $Q$. The intersection with the number line is then $A\times B$.

**Remark:** In standard geometry (that is, construction with compass and ruler), you of course need to draw circles to construct the parallel. But one might instead consider using no compass, but a “parallels-ruler" (I have no idea what it is actually called; it's basically a ruler that has a built-in roll, allowing you to move the ruler without rotating, and thus to construct parallels).

With only a parallels-ruler you cannot construct circles (so it's strictly weaker than compass and ruler), but as the construction above shows, you can multiply.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct two similar triangles $X_1Y_1Z_1$ and $X_2Y_2Z_2$ such that $X_1Y_1=1$, $Y_1Z_1 = A$, and $X_2Y_2 = B$, then $Y_2Z_2=A*B$.

Also, if you take any angle, mark $1$ and $A$ on one side, mark $B$ on another, draw a line from the $A$ point to the $B$ point, then construct a line parallel through that line through the $1$ point, it will intersect the other side a distance $\frac B A$ from the vertex. And $A*B$ is of course equal to $A/(1/B)$.

Comment: I added your construction to my big list.

Comment: Isn't it the Method 3?