# Multiplication and Equivalent Geometrical Figure

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

Just like we visualize multiplication of two numbers as a rectangle, multiplication of three numbers as a cube, how can we visualize the multiplication of four and higher numbers? Is there any geometric equivalent figure?

The reason for asking is: with a rectangle and cube it is easy to accept the fact that the order of multiplication does not affect the product. But, it gets complicated when we multiply four or more numbers.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155691/equivalence-of-different-ways-of-geometrical-multiplication) may help.